# Using 3 fair 6-sided dice, what is the probability of rolling 2 or more dice with the same number?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Using 3 fair 6-sided dice, what is the probability of rolling 2 or more dice with the same number?

I.e., 3,3,1 or 4,4,4 ?

Comment: Hint:  it's esier to compute the probability that they all differ.

Comment: It has been decades since taking Statistics, and the little bit I remember is to take the total number of possible results [216] as a divisor, and list all the possible combinations to get a percentage.  Is there a formula that accomplishes this?

Comment: Suggest you pursue @lulu's excellent Hint, and edit progress into your Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(\text{$2$ or $3$ the same})$ = $1-P(\text{all different})$, and to get the chance of them being all different, note that the first die can be anything, the second needs to be different from the first (the chance of which is $\frac{5}{6}$), and the third needs to be different from the first two (the chance of which, given that the first two are already different, is $\frac{4}{6}$. So, $P(\text{all different})=1\cdot \frac{5}{6}\cdot \frac{4}{6} = \frac{5}{9}$. Hence, the chance of two or more being the same is $1-\frac{5}{9}=\frac{4}{9}$.

Answer (score 1):

In total you have $6*6*6=216$ cases. If the first two dices have the same number, then there are $6*6=36$ variants (6 for the number on 1 and 2 and another 6 for the third).Similarly you have 36 cases when the third and the second have the same number and more 36 when first and third coincide. But you have counted the cases when the three numbers coicide three times, so we have to add back $2*6$. At the end, probability is $\frac{3*36-12}{216}=\frac{96}{216}=\frac{4}{9}$

Comment: thefunkyjunky:

I may be misunderstanding your explanation, so if you could take the time to define your terms, it would help. 

:)

Comment: @JasMillard What do you mean? I've used both cases and variants to denote some result after throwing the dices like (1, 3, 2), aside from this I think the rest is clear. Tell me if some other terms are confusing you.

Comment: I guess he means he is confused by your answer, which could use some clarification.

Answer (score 0):

**Comment:** Two different solutions, previously. I believe @Bram28 has given a clear and correct solution.

Below is a simulation of a million 3-dice experiments, in which $X$ is the number of unique faces seen in any one such experiment. Results should be
accurate to two or three places.

```
 m = 10^6;  n = 3;  x = numeric(m)
 for (i in 1:m) {
  faces = sample(1:6, n, rep=T)
  x[i] = length(unique(faces)) }
 table(x)/m
## x
##        1        2        3 
## 0.027747 0.416532 0.555721 
c(1, 15, 20)/36
## 0.02777778 0.41666667 0.55555556
```

Results are consistent with $P(\text{all faces same}) = P(X=1) = 1/36,$
$P(X=2) = 15/36,$ and $P(\text{all faces different}) = P(X=3) = 20/36.$

So the desired answer is $P(X \le 2) = 1 - P(X=3) = 1 - 20/36 = 4/9).$